# Problems with webcam

Tags: windows-7, drivers, troubleshooting, skype, webcam

My friend is using Windows 8.1, and he has a webcam. He says it is working very well even without installing drivers.

Webcam is **A4tech - PK-331F**.
[image]

I asked for this webcam for use.

I plugged in the webcam, and Windows detected it and installed drivers automatically. Then I opened Skype to check the webcam. I got a message from Skype that said, "Your webcam has microphone." When I clicked over it, it directed me to sound settings where it showed that the webcam microphone was working. I went to video settings, but the webcam wasn't listed there.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the webcam is not listed. It *is* listed in Device Manager but isn't listed in Skype.

**I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. Any idea why this is happening?**

---

**UPDATE**
Here is the hardware lds from webcam installed drivers.

> USB\VID_0AC8&PID_3420&REV_5000&MI_00
>   USB\VID_0AC8&PID_3420&MI_00

---

**Update**
I found an question related to webcam. After the reading answer, I read that OP had problem with its PC. I am sharing my PC specifications if that helps.

> Dell Optiplex 960
>   Dell Inc. 0H634K *(Motherboard)*
>   Intel core 2 Duo E8500 - 3.1 Ghz
>   5GB Ram
>   AMD Radeon HD 5450 1GB
>   Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Comment: Please include more details in your question. What webcam model is it? Can you specify what you mean by "*doesn't work*"? Is the picture black? Or maybe it doesn't show up in Skype or Devices? (you can edit the question)

Comment: @gronostaj I have edited the question. It doesn't show up in skype but it's microphone is working.

Comment: It wasn't listed in Skype or Skype could not display the video capture?

Comment: Device manager show "it is installed" but skype says "No device detected".

Comment: Does the device show a driver is installed?

Comment: @ramhound I have added an image.

Comment: My guess is the camera isn't actually supported.  On the windows 8 machine desktop or modern UI version of Skype?

Comment: Try using drivereasy, maybe windows hasn't installed the correct drivers

Comment: Please don't that sounds like malware

Comment: @ramhound malware?

Comment: That 'drivereasy' thing. Tools like that usually install together with a lot of useless stuff or even malware. Right-click the webcam in Device Manager, click *Properties*, *Details* tab, choose *Hardware Ids* and tell us what's there. (you can copy from right-click menu or with Ctrl+C)

Comment: @gronostaj I have updated with **hardware lds**.

Comment: Download drivers for [this camera](http://www.canyon.eu/archive/companions/webcams/CNR-WCAM713#pr-switcher) and install them, then connect your camera and see if it starts to work

Comment: @gronostaj black screen as before but this time Skype detected it.

Comment: I have ran out of ideas. Maybe others will come up with something.

Comment: I don't have another computer so that I could have checked it on it, it can be possible that camera is malfunctioned.

Comment: Are there any moving parts? Some cameras turn off when rotated down etc.

Comment: @gronostaj there is just one button in front of camera as you can see in image.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: @gronostaj nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: @gronostaj I am updated the question with PC specification. I am using 64bit operating system.

Comment: First remove any drivers installed (including the windows driver). Then reboot your computer with webcam unplugged (please don't skip this step!). Install the drivers from the manufacturer. Then insert the webcam.

Comment: @agtoever what you mean by **windows driver**?

Comment: Windows driver: right click in de device manager on your device (the webcam). On the "Driver" tab click "Uninstall driver". That removes the default Windows driver for this device, that maybe doesn't work in your case or that maybe conflicts with another installed driver for that device.

Comment: Try downloading and installing the following driver: http://www.eng.defender-global.com/support/drivers/12463/

Comment: @and31415 you have provided same as other user.

Comment: @Murtaza It's not the same actually, it's a slightly different version. I assume you tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: @Murtaza contact the developers. Here is there email: http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=pk-333e

Comment: @devid I already have sent them a massage and waiting for response.

Comment: @Murtaza: Please test your cam using [manycam](http://download.manycam.com/) or [youcam](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01414839). This is only for testing.

Comment: @renjuchandranchingath I have tested it on [this](webcamtoy.com) site but didn't work so will it work on these software?

Comment: @Murtaza: I cant say "for sure". but please try it. lets confirm that its not working in anyways. Also did you have any other webcam with you for testing?

Comment: @renjuchandranchingath I don't have extra webcam for test not another computer to check this one.

Comment: Sorry everyone. I tested this webcam on other computer and it was catching same wrong drivers so I think webcam is malfunctioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the desired [driver](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/webcam/a4tech/pc-cam/pk-331f/model-numbers/).
2. Save it somewhere where you will remember after the download has been completed.
3. After successfully downloading the driver, do not open the driver file until you make sure the following has completed: Uninstall any original drivers for the webcam from the PC.
4. After the original webcam driver has been removed,  open the downloaded file.
5. Install the downloaded driver/s.
6. When it's successfully installed, restart your PC.
7. After you have restarted your PC, plug the webcam into your computer and it will automatically recognize the new hardware.

Comment: I already have done this but didn't work. Also you should add this in your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem before. You should manually try to download the drivers required for the A4tech - PK-331F.

You can get those here: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/webcam/a4tech/pc-cam/pk-331f/model-numbers/

Good luck!

Comment: Windows is installing old drivers and this software while scanning in outdated drivers but when I install new drivers recommended by user in comment than it doesn't show up in outdated drivers, that means I have installed latest drivers and still webcam isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest driver and install for your webcam , see if the problem is persists.

Select PK-331F press Go

http://www.a4tech.com/download.asp