# How to prevent Windows from doing this

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

[image]
This is my webcam. It is first time using this webcam in my pc. It's name is **A4tech - PK-331F**.
When I plugged that webcam, windows start installing drivers automatically but unfortunately it installed wrong drivers. The drivers Windows 7 installed are **Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera (Venus)** and these drivers aren't related to this webcam.
Now I did some modifications to windows so it isn't installing drivers automatically but whenever I plug that webcam but same name of drivers and doesn't install it. I think because of it, I can't install it's original drivers.

[image]

I don't want Windows recognize this webcam with this name. How can I prevent Windows from doing this?.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the drivers from the manufactures website?  [Link](http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=pk-333e)

Comment: Yes but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fix the name. That is the name that the camera is reporting to Windows. It's very likely that the camera is rebranded (Vimicro makes the camera electronics, A4Tech buys them in bulk from Vimicro and puts their label on it. You'd be surprised how often this is done).

You should install the proper drivers from A4Tech first (@Malcolm has provided a [**link**](http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=pk-333e)), and then connect the camera.

Comment: These have installed these drivers but doesn't work. My friends has Windows 8.1 and this webcam is working to my friend's PC.

Comment: More info is in that [question](http://superuser.com/questions/800186/problems-with-webcam).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Doesn't work"? What driver does the device try to use according to the device manager? (Right-Click on the device > Properties). Keep in mind that Windows 8 has many more drivers built-in than Windows 7.

Comment: @Murtaza have you checked the Notes on the Driver Information site provided in the link ? There you can find also a email for further support.

Comment: A quibble: The device only returns a PnP ID 9vendor, product, version, etc., codes) to Windows. The device name text comes from an .INF file that contains a matching PnP ID. The .INF file also contains the file spec for the required driver binary, sets registry values as required, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If You did some modifications to windows so it isn't installing drivers automatically, then go to device manager and uninstall Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera driver that windows automatically installed it before